# Eye for eye, and tooth for tooth

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

[image][image]
[image][image]

Hints:

> The final solution will be an image you know well

Answer (score 18, accepted):

continuing where rand al'thor stopped.

> we now got the mail with
>  our code
>  05N7g
>  05,12    08,11   10,09   12,19   14,19   16,09  18,11   19,12   21,12
>  05,10   07,10   09,06   10,07   12,17   13,16  16,07   17,06   21,10
>
>  05N7g, is again an imgur picture
>  which is the same as before but without the letters
>  marking the coordinates in this pattern
>  connecting them and cutting them out
>  [image]
>
>  It's our icon
>  [image]
>
> ---
>
> Think grid points, not squares, and connect them:
>  
>  [image]

Comment: >! the black lines sadly cover the colors beneath

Comment: To put a spoiler in a comment, write something like `[hover for spoiler](http://stackexchange.com "text inside spoiler")`, like this: [hover for spoiler](http://stackexchange.com "text inside spoiler")

Comment: This doesn't work for mobile.

Comment: How do you explain the title?

Comment: @ais523 no you use rot13

Answer (score 13):

The puzzle consists of four images, each of which is a reddish square with five characters in it. Using those five-character strings as Imgur codes, we get the following four new images:

> [image: First] [image: Second]
>  [image: Third] [image: Fourth]

Putting them all together yields a single image:

> [image: Whole grid]

This gives the following instruction:

> SEND EMAIL WITH QUESTION ID AS SUBJECT.

I sent an email to the address mentioned in the OP's profile (`incesterror21@gmail.com`), and got an auto-generated reply which contained the following text in various formats:

> `05N7g`
>
>  `05,12   08,11   10,09   12,19   14,19   16,09   18,11   19,12   21,12`
>  `05,10   07,10   09,06   10,07   12,17   13,16   16,07   17,06   21,10`

The first five characters are yet another Imgur code, yielding the same combined image grid as above except without the letters:

> [image: Grid]

So I'm guessing the numbers can be interpreted as positions on this grid, in order to yield colours which can be put together for the final solution.

Comment: The five characters in the email correspond to this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/05N7g.png

Answer (score 3):

**Partial**

Following @rand-al'thor's answer

> When you email the OP's email address from his SE profile with question ID (51547) as subject, you receive an automated reply:
>
> `05N7g
>
>  05,12    08,11   10,09   12,19   14,19   16,09   18,11   19,12   21,12
>  05,10    07,10   09,06   10,07   12,17   13,16   16,07   17,06   21,10`

Then

> The two lines of numbers looked like `x,y` coordinates to me.
>
>  This gives us something like this:
>
>  [image]
>
>  Which looks like a [space invader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Invaders) to me :)
>
>  [image]

**Update**:

> Placing the coordinate-generated image on the image with colors we get:
>
>  [image]
>   OR
>  
>  [image]
>
>  Ignoring the black border.
>
>  It covers 4 colored tiles in both cases:
>  RRGR or RGRR (top to bottom, left to right)

Comment: The first few alphanumeric is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05N7g.png)